# What could cause Range.Copy to throw an error?

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following line in my VBA code:

```
wks.Rows(lLastRow).Copy
```

Usually it works fine. lLastRow is always 11. wks is always the active sheet.

But sometimes the line above starts throwing errors of the type: "copy method of range class failed".

Then I have to restart the Excel file for the line to start working again.

Do you have any idea what might be causing the problem? What could cause a `Range.Copy` statement to stop working and then start working again once the file is restarted?

**EDIT**: Here is more of my code. The code is started by a button calling `NewActionButton()`

```
Sub NewActionButton()
    'Dim runState As New cRunState
    'Set runState = New cRunState
    If bProduction = True Then On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    'START
    Dim lStart As Long
    Dim lId As Long
    Dim lDate As Long
    Dim lEnd As Long
    Dim wks As Worksheet

    Set wks = GetSheetByCodename(ThisWorkbook, "wActions")
    lStart = 2
    lId = 3
    lDate = 2
    lEnd = 12

    Call NewRow(wks, lStart, lId, lDate, lEnd)
    'END

    On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox ("Ett of" & oe & "rutsett fel har skett.")
End Sub
```

The procedure in which I get an error. the first time it fails it seems to throw an error on the .Insert statement. Then if I run the macro again it throws an error on the .Copy statement. If I restart the document, it works.

```
Sub NewRow(wks As Worksheet, lStartCol As Long, lIdCol As Long, lDate As Long, lEndCol As Long)
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    Dim rConstants As Range
    Dim rConstant As Range
    Dim rEarlierIds As Range

    'Determine last row based on criteria column
    lLastRow = LastRow(wks.Columns(lIdCol))

    'Copy template row from directly above
    wks.Range(wks.Cells(lLastRow, lStartCol), wks.Cells(lLastRow, lEndCol)).Copy

    'Insert new row
    wks.Range(wks.Cells(lLastRow + 1, lStartCol), wks.Cells(lLastRow + 1, lEndCol)).Insert

    'Remove unwanted properties
    Set rConstants = wks.Range(wks.Cells(lLastRow + 1, lStartCol), wks.Cells(lLastRow + 1, lEndCol)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If Not rConstants Is Nothing Then
        For Each rConstant In rConstants.Cells
            rConstant = ""
        Next rConstant
    End If

    'Add ID
    Set rEarlierIds = wks.Columns(lIdCol)
    wks.Cells(lLastRow + 1, lIdCol) = Evaluate("Max(" & rEarlierIds.Address & ")+1")

    'Add Date
    wks.Cells(lLastRow + 1, lDate) = Date

    'Remove copy marking
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

**EDIT2**: The .Insert statement does insert a new range. Yet, despite this, execution stops and I get the error message "Insert method of Range class failed. So the line does it jobs, yet I get an error and execution stops.

**EDIT3**: I don't know what is wrong, but I have discovered a pattern. The .Insert statement works if I execute the macro immedietly after opening the Excel file. And I can execute it any number of times. But as soon as I double click on a cell and then click ESC to leave the cell, and then try running the macro again, then the .Insert statement throws an error. This makes no sense to me.

**EDIT4**:I have update the code above to how it currently looks.

**EDIT5**:The code below works flawlessly. What I have changed is that I don't copy and then insert. Instead I first insert a new row and then copy to it. I still don't know why my previous code didn't work. I hope someone has an idea or can confirm that I stumbled upon a bug and can say something about what circumstances cause the bug.

```
Sub NewRow(wks As Worksheet, lStartCol As Long, lIdCol As Long, lDate As Long, lEndCol As Long)
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    Dim rConstants As Range
    Dim rConstant As Range
    Dim rEarlierIds As Range

    'Determine last row based on criteria column
    lLastRow = LastRow(wks.Columns(lIdCol))

    'Insert new row
    wks.Range(wks.Cells(lLastRow + 1, lStartCol), wks.Cells(lLastRow + 1, lEndCol)).Insert

    'Copy template row from directly above
    wks.Range(wks.Cells(lLastRow, lStartCol), wks.Cells(lLastRow, lEndCol)).Copy

    'Paste formulas row
    wks.Range(wks.Cells(lLastRow + 1, lStartCol), wks.Cells(lLastRow + 1, lEndCol)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

    'Remove values
    Set rConstants = wks.Range(wks.Cells(lLastRow + 1, lStartCol), wks.Cells(lLastRow + 1, lEndCol)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If Not rConstants Is Nothing Then
        For Each rConstant In rConstants.Cells
            rConstant = ""
        Next rConstant
    End If

    'Add ID
    Set rEarlierIds = wks.Columns(lIdCol)
    wks.Cells(lLastRow + 1, lIdCol) = Evaluate("Max(" & rEarlierIds.Address & ")+1")

    'Add Date
    wks.Cells(lLastRow + 1, lDate) = Date

    'Remove copy marking
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: A couple of comments:  do you ever set Application.CutCopyMode to False?  Also, in the NewRow() sub, what is the benefit of using the LastRow() function?  Could you instead utilize built-in functions to determine the last row?

Comment: A1: I didn't before. I added it to my code after making this post, to get rid of the marking around the copied range. Other than that, I don't know if there are any other benefits to it. I'll read up. However, I am still having problems, even after I added CutCopyMode = False to the end of the procedure. A2: Built-in functions like Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row or End(xlUp) don't register text that is hidden by filters.

Comment: Does the copy row have a lot of formatting/text inside?  Could Excel be running out of memory because the Clipboard already has the previous row and is trying to copy the row again?  I would try to copy a blank cell directly before wks.Rows(lLastRow).Copy to "clear" the Clipboard and see if this helps.

Comment: I have modified the text so that only 11 cells are are copied and inserted instead of the entire row. When I get the error message it seems like the workbook becomes locked up somehow. I can't select cells by clicking on them. However if I double-click on them, I can write in them. Just now I double clicked on a cell and could start writing in it. But then Excel crashed a in the middle of my typing.

Comment: The first time I get an error after opening the Workbook, it is always Run-time error -2147417848 (80010108): Method Insert of Object Range failed.

Comment: I would activate the worksheet object you're using the copy/paste method on using worksheet.activate since you're activating it from passing your module function it might not be fully activated in the active application objects

Comment: Have you checked that after you've been in a cell the used range isn't being set include all rows? This could cause an error because the insert function can't "shift" any more. If this is the case, then I would check any event procedures that you may have to see what's causing it.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to the fact that VB commands usually correspond to commands that Excel carries out in its own interface. Most of the time, this doesn't cause any issues - actually it's why Macro recording works (even if it doesn't work very well). Occasionally you get quirks, though. This smells like one of them (one of the others involving copy/paste is often any interactions on the workbook layer OTHER than a paste command will result in an InvalidOperation Exception when paste is eventually called).

In this case, I'd suggest copying some cells, then right clicking on any column or row. You'll note that the insert option is totally eliminated - there's only an option to "Insert Copied Cells". This remains true for as long as the worksheet is in `CutCopyMode`; when it comes out of it, the Insert option returns. My guess is either

- Your code attempts to Insert (rather than Insert Copied Cells) when it's a forbidden action or
- Your code attempts to Insert Copied Cells when the range it is trying to be inserted into is only ready to insert some blank ones.

To be sure of this, though, you'd probably have to decompile both methods, which is way beyond me. Glad to hear you've come up with a solution though.